# LNK1104 error when building Rhapsody 7.6.1 component

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, rhapsody

i'm using the Rhapsody 7.6.1 For C++ with the visual Studio 2010
already installed and set as described on this page: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21511885

when trying to build my component i face these two errors:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DoGiS.png)

can you help me please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To close this question for those who are following it, after few days of searching and working on this issue, i've noticed that the cause was a damaged ".exe" file whose role is to parse my project's Objects folder and create a text file "objs_files.lst" containing the name of all the generated object files of that folder:

/******objs_files.lst ******/
obj\Launcher.obj
obj\LauncherSimulationWin32.obj
obj\DistantFServer.obj
obj\HardwareDriversFactory.obj
...etc
/*********************************/

this file was not created since my "objectfilegenerator.exe" is damaged, so i've created a small c++ .exe to do that job ==> as a result both errors are solved.